# Example of table function

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

Is the `UNNEST` an example of a table-function? It seems to produce a single named column if I'm understanding it correctly. Something like:

```
`vals`
[1,2,3]

unnest(vals) as v
`v`
1
2
3
```

```
with Table as (
  select [1,2,3] vals
 ) select v from Table, UNNEST(vals) as v
```

Is this an example of a table-function? If not, what kind of function is it? Are there any other predefined table functions in BQ?

Comment: UNNEST is a table function. Another one is EXTERNAL_QUERY() https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/cloud-sql-federated-queries#federated_query_syntax

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The UNNEST operator takes an ARRAY and returns a table, with one row for each element in the ARRAY. You can also use UNNEST outside of the FROM clause with the IN operator.

So, you might may call it table function if you wish :o)

You can read more about UNNEST [here](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/query-syntax#unnest)

> It seems to produce a single named column if I'm understanding it correctly

Not exactly correct. See example below

```
with Table as (
  select [struct(1 as a,2 as b),struct(3, 4), struct(5, 6)] vals
) 
select v.* from Table, UNNEST(vals) as v
```

with output

[image]

Comment: cool, are there any other table functions that you know of that BQ supports natively?

Comment: there are no more that are natively supported

Comment: Thanks -- could you please show an example or a link for doing: `You can also use UNNEST outside of the FROM clause with the IN operator` ?

Comment: example: `where col in unnest([1, 2, 3])`